# Displaying an error message for non-existent city?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help with displaying an error when a user inputs a non-existent city. The app currently crashes but it should display "Please enter existing city". Сan anyone help with this?

Нужно помочь с написанием ошибки. Например, когда пользователи вводят несуществующий город, приложение не крашится, но оно должно показывать: пожалуйста, напишите существующий город. Может кто-нибудь помочь с этим?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import WeatherInput from "./WeatherInput";

const KEY = "455137f97981800c10482bbc6539fba2";

class Weather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      city: "",
      country: "",
      temperature: "",
      main: "",
      description: "",
      error: ""
    };
  }

  getWeatherInfo = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const city = event.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = event.value;
    const api = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country},uk&APPID=${KEY}`
    );
    const data = await api.json();
    if (city) {
      this.setState({
        city: data.name,
        country: data.sys.country,
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        main: data.weather[0].main,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error: ""
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        city: "",
        country: "",
        temperature: "",
        main: "",
        description: "",
        error: "Please enter the values."
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { city, country, temperature, main, description, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <WeatherInput
        getWeatherInfo={this.getWeatherInfo}
        city={city}
        country={country}
        temperature={temperature}
        main={main}
        description={description}
        error={error}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: When you say crashes, what error are you getting?

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'country' of undefined

Comment: And you've tried to console.log the event? Not sure what is in WeatherInput but usually with an input you would get the value from event.target.value

Comment: Everything working perfect but when I enter non-existent city and search, its crashing and error: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined. But, I want, when I enter non-existent city display an error message Please enter existing city

Comment: So you are checking if City exsits but you are not checking if Country exists. Maybe add that to your check? `if (city && country)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code

```
if (city) {
```

just checks if there is a value for const city. Which is always true, even if the user gave a non-existent city.

It is the API that checks if the city exists. If it doesn't, it will return this:

```
{
    "cod": "404",
    "message": "city not found"
}
```

So you need to use this info from the API. One way is to say, OK, if the city exists, the API returns a 'name' field; if not, there is no 'name' field:

```
 const data = await api.json();

    if (data.name) {
      this.setState({
        city: data.name,
        country: data.sys.country,
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        main: data.weather[0].main,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error: ""
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        city: "",
        country: "",
        temperature: "",
        main: "",
        description: "",
        error: "Please enter the values."
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are getting an error about `country` being undefined so you need more checking around this.

For a start if country is undefined what do you want to do? If you want it to error in the same way as if `city` is undefined then add it to your if statement like this:

`if (city && country)`

If you don't care that `country` is undefined and simply want to check city, set your country variable to an empty string if it is not already set:

`const country = event.value || ''`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Jon! I really appreciate it!